# How to convert decimal to binary number in prolog.?

Tags: prolog

```
dec_bin(1,1).
dec_bin(N,B):-N>1,X is N mod 2,Y is N//2,dec_bin(Y,B1),B=B1+X.
```

This gives me the output :

```
?- dec_bin(12,K).
K = 1+1+0+0.
```

But I want just 1100 without '+' symbol. Please someone help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your are looking after is `atom_concat/3`. 
Also note that your procedure is failing on input number 0.

```
dec_bin(0,'0').
dec_bin(1,'1').
dec_bin(N,B):-N>1,X is N mod 2,Y is N//2,dec_bin(Y,B1),atom_concat(B1, X, B).
```

?- dec_bin(12,K). K = '1100'